# Compiler error while installing netbeans 10 with ant

Tags: ant

I've tried different JDK's, their version but still getting this error.

Linux Mint Tessa 19.1 x64

```
 Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1101      auto mode
* 1            /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java               100       manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1101      manual mode
```

```
C:\Netbeans10>ant
Buildfile: C:\Netbeans10\build.xml

-jdk-pre-preinit:

-jdk-preinit:

-jdk-warn:

-jdk-presetdef-basic:

-jdk-default:

-jdk-init:

-load-build-properties:

bootstrap:
     [echo] Bootstrapping NetBeans-specific Ant extensions...

init-tasks:

-check-vanilla-javac:

prepare-vanilla-javac:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\external\langtools-9.zip into C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

-def-check:

-check-langtools.jdk.home:

-prepare-build:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\modules
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\toolclasses
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\gensrc
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\prevsrc

-def-pparse:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\toolclasses\propertiesparser
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\toolclasses

-def-pcompile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\toolclasses

generate-sources:
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

generate-sources-internal:
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

generate-sources-internal:
   [pparse] Generating 1 resource files to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\gensrc\jdk.compiler
 [pcompile] Generating 15 resource files to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\gensrc\jdk.compiler
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

generate-sources-internal:
 [pcompile] Generating 18 resource files to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\gensrc\jdk.javadoc
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

generate-sources-internal:
 [pcompile] Generating 10 resource files to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\gensrc\jdk.jdeps
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
[pathconvert] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

generate-sources-internal:
 [pcompile] Generating 6 resource files to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\gensrc\jdk.jshell
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\nb
    [javac] Compiling 1031 source files to C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\build\nb
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\java.compiler\share\classes\javax\annotation\processing\Messager.java:28: error: package javax.annotation does not exist
    [javac] import javax.annotation.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.compiler\share\classes\com\sun\tools\javac\model\AnnotationProxyMaker.java:35: error: package sun.reflect.annotation is not visible
    [javac] import sun.reflect.annotation.*;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac]   (package sun.reflect.annotation is declared in module java.base, which does not export it to module java.compiler)
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\com\sun\tools\doclets\internal\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:31: error: package javax.xml.parsers is not visible
    [javac] import javax.xml.parsers.*;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac]   (package javax.xml.parsers is declared in module java.xml, but module java.compiler does not read it)
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\com\sun\tools\doclets\internal\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:33: error: package org.xml.sax is not visible
    [javac] import org.xml.sax.*;
    [javac]               ^
    [javac]   (package org.xml.sax is declared in module java.xml, but module java.compiler does not read it)
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\com\sun\tools\doclets\internal\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:34: error: package org.xml.sax.helpers is not visible
    [javac] import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac]   (package org.xml.sax.helpers is declared in module java.xml, but module java.compiler does not read it)
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\jdk\javadoc\internal\doclets\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:31: error: package javax.xml.parsers is not visible
    [javac] import javax.xml.parsers.*;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac]   (package javax.xml.parsers is declared in module java.xml, but module java.compiler does not read it)
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\jdk\javadoc\internal\doclets\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:36: error: package org.xml.sax is not visible
    [javac] import org.xml.sax.*;
    [javac]               ^
    [javac]   (package org.xml.sax is declared in module java.xml, but module java.compiler does not read it)
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\jdk\javadoc\internal\doclets\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:37: error: package org.xml.sax.helpers is not visible
    [javac] import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac]   (package org.xml.sax.helpers is declared in module java.xml, but module java.compiler does not read it)
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\com\sun\tools\doclets\internal\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:105: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\com\sun\tools\doclets\internal\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:122: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\jdk\javadoc\internal\doclets\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:110: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build\langtools\src\jdk.javadoc\share\classes\jdk\javadoc\internal\doclets\toolkit\builders\LayoutParser.java:126: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] 12 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\Netbeans10\nbbuild\build.xml:151: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 minute 49 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to the JDK 8 version. In my case (debian 9): JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

I had this problem when trying yo use ant with a newer JDK (9).